# Converting a hexadecimal string to a decimal number

Tags: type-conversion, crystal-lang

In Ruby one can convert a hexadecimal string to a decimal number with `String#hex` method:

```
"1a2f".hex # => 6703
```

How to do that in Crystal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`String#to_i`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.25.1/String.html#to_i%28base%3AInt%3D10%2Cwhitespace%3Dtrue%2Cunderscore%3Dfalse%2Cprefix%3Dfalse%2Cstrict%3Dtrue%2C%26block%29-instance-method) with a base of 16:

```
"1a2f".to_i(16) # => 6703
```